# Why is this PHP while query not working?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this simple pre-sort database input thing, I've created this before, what I'm screwing up is the while aspect.

There are two different tables: a table that keeps track of keyword frequencies and a table for the entries themselves paired with the keyword.

What I'm doing is saving something by a keyword, I check if the keyword exists, if it does, I increment the count of that keyword and then proceed to add the entry to the entry database, if not I create a new entry of that keyword in the keyword table and set the count as 1, then add the entry to the entry database.

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM key WHERE key=?";
if($stmt = $link->prepare($query)){
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$key);
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch_row()){
        $count = $row[0];
    }

    // count comes out here
    // echo $count;
    if($count==0){
        // insert new entry
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO entry VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('issss',$id,$poster,$key,$entry,$date);
        $stmt->execute();

        // insert new key
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO key VALUES (?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('isi',$id,$key,$numtimes);
        $stmt->execute();
    } else {
        // insert new entry
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO entry VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('issss',$id,$poster,$key,$entry,$date);
        $stmt->execute();

        // update key count
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "UPDATE key SET numtimes=key+1 WHERE key=$key");
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$key);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: first of all declare $count=0; before while loop , suppose if there is no data the row then $count is nothing , you have used it only in while first

Comment: I don't understand, this is roughly how I have used this method before. I have never declared count, it was a result of the query. So if there is no data according to *successful* msql query, then the row would be 0.

Comment: Please indent that code correctly. (Kinda relevant if it's about the while blocks specifically.)

Comment: @janicehoplin mysqli_fetch_row() returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row or NULL if there are no more rows in result set.

Comment: @janicehoplin http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php check yourself

Comment: I wonder if there should/could be a paid version of stackoverflow where you ask a question/paste code and people fix it no questions ask (of course you pay for it). Anyway thanks for responding to my post albeit the result.

Comment: @mario, I comprehend your suggestion on indentation for readability despite php/everything parsing from left to right character after character, but I don't follow convention as I work on my own projects/ not for the industry yet here I am asking for others who conform to a common accepted practice so I apologize.

Comment: the problem with your suggestion sandeepKumar about checking the manual is that it is not a prepared statement. Although I imagine the procedure remains mostly the same despite the two added lines for preparing a statement. It is so aggravating on my part to lose 5 months of work where I have gone through the process of making an ass of myself asking these questions and getting the results only to do it again. It is my fault, crappy drives that fail to transfer data without damage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM key WHERE key=?";
if($stmt = $link->prepare($query)){
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $key);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()){
        $count = $row[0];
    }
    $stmt->close();

    // count comes out here
    // echo $count;
    if($count == 0){
        // insert new entry
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO entry VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('issss', $id, $poster, $key, $entry, $date);
        $stmt->execute();

        // insert new key
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO key VALUES (?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('isi',$id,$key,$numtimes);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    } else {
        // insert new entry
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO entry VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('issss',$id,$poster,$key,$entry,$date);
        $stmt->execute();

        // update key count
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "UPDATE key SET numtimes=key+1 WHERE key=$key");
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$key);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
?>
```

This should do the trick for you, you can't use fetch_row() directly on $stmt, that was your mistake.

Comment: I actually had to use num_rows as for some reason fetch_row / fetch_all would not work even after installing php5-mysqlnd so whatever, at least I got it to work, there was so much crap I had to deal with like key is a reserved word too, that's another problem. Anyway thank you. This is what happens when you mash things together to try and get something to work and not follow the linear progress of learning.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues

1. first

   `while ($row = $stmt->fetch_row()){
       $count = $row[0];
   }`

should be replaced by simply

```
$count = $stmt-rowCount()
```

2. You actually don't need the 'keys' table. Consider your DB schema again. The keys table is superfluous. The 'entry' table will suffice just update the entry table and you are good. All information can be obtained by querying the entry table rightly